# How can I draw an arrow indicating math text?

Tags: tikz-arrows

I need help drawing or putting somehow an arrow that indicate the fraction (like in the picture):

[image]

My code is this:

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
   E(X)&=\sum_{k=0}^3kP(X=k) \\
   &=0\cdot P(X=0)+1\cdot P(X=1)+2\cdot P(X=2)+3\cdot P(X=3) \\
   &=\frac{3}{8}+2\left(\frac{3}{8}\right)+3\left(\frac{1}{8}\right) \\
   &=3\left(\frac{1}{2}\right
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `\underset` and `\substack`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
   E(X)&=\sum_{k=0}^3kP(X=k) \\
   &=0\cdot P(X=0)+1\cdot P(X=1)+2\cdot P(X=2)+3\cdot P(X=3) \\
   &=\frac{3}{8}+2\left(\frac{3}{8}\right)+3\left(\frac{1}{8}\right) \\
   &=\underset{\substack{\downarrow \\ n}}{3\vphantom{\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)}}
     \underset{\substack{\downarrow \\ p}}{\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```